# Which event handler I must use to check whether I have checked CheckBox in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I am having a DataGridView with 3 columns. Delete, User Name, Password. Delete column hosts a CheckBox, the other 2 are text. The DataGridView is named grid1.

I am trying to check if user has clicked the CheckBox field by using event handler. Problem is that I'm not sure what should I use to add handler to. Should I use `grid.(...)` or `Delete.(...)` and which property of should I use? Which event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try handling the DataGridView CellContentClick event:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(e.RowIndex.ToString()+" and "+e.ColumnIndex.ToString());
}
```

You then need to test the column index to check it is your checkbox column.

You can get the checked state of each checkbox by inspecting the 'value' of each cell:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridRow in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
   var checked = ((DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)dataGridRow.Cells["checkbox_col"]).Value;
}
```

Comment: Why iterate over all cells? You can just use the CellValueChanged event and get the rowindex and column index from it's args.